# How to use ssh-copy-id with vagrant? It keeps asking for .pub

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, vagrant

I have been trying to use add ssh key to vagrant VMs through this command.

```
ssh-copy-id -f -i .vagrant/machines/workers/virtualbox/private_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no vagrant@192.168.5.30
```

The error is

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file .vagrant/machines/workers/virtualbox/private_key.pub'
```

The problem is I am assigning `private_key` but it is keep asking for `.pub` that doesn't exist. How can I force ssh to take `private_key`?

Also I tried to rename `private_key` to `private_key.pub` and it returns

`vagrant@192.168.5.30: Permission denied (publickey).`

I just want to access to vagrant VM with command `ssh vagrant@192.168.5.30`(without password) instead of `vagrant ssh workers`

Comment: You should never ever under any circumstances copy your private key to any other server. This is not how key based authentication works. Renaming the privatekey to `*.pub` will not magically make it the publickey of the keypair. You may want to educate yourself and [meet alice and bob](https://wordtothewise.com/2014/09/cryptography-alice-bob/) before proceeding to setup technology that you do not understand yet. If you are missing the publickey, generate a new keypair with `ssh-keygen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hidden from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864372/how-to-ssh-to-vagrant-without-actually-running-vagrant-ssh#:%7E:text=Simply%20CMD%2DSHIFT%2DP%20then,to%20your%20remote%20vagrant%20vm!)

The step I used is here

0. If you are like me and tried a few commands, you might accidentally add the key to known host. Run `vim /Users/[your user]/.ssh/known_hosts`. Then delete all the known hosts with name `127.0.0.1`(vim command to delete a line is `dd`).
1. `vagrant ssh-config` - I will get the info I need from this command. Choose which node you want to ssh to. Under the `Host` you want to, that's the information you need.
2. Use the info in step 1 and compose the command like this `[User]@[HostName] -p [Port] -i [IdentityFile]`

Have fun!